# xjc type definition name resolution error

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb, xjc, xml-binding

I am running into troubles when wanting to compile my XSDs (which I am not the author of) with XJC.

Specifically, I get the error (there are actually more like these):

```
 [ERROR] src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name "ifopt:CountryRefStructure" to a(n) 'type definition' component.
   line 131 of file:/E:/ansdef/schema/siri-1.3/siri/siri_situationIdentity-v1.1.xsd
```

That is strange since the mentioned file (`siri_situationIdentity-v1.1.xsd`) refers to another XSD where the suspicious type is declared.

I tried several things

- switch Java version to get different xjc
- tried some different xjc directly from java.net
- applied some modifications to the files so that the currently applied JAXB workarounds regarding includes/imports are removed
- tried to use the whole directory with dependent schemas as target for xjc
- Altova XMLSpy Java code generation works well without errors (but is no way to go for me)

None of them worked.

Does anybody have a clue what the error message is caused by? I don't see the point.
You may get all the XSDs directly from here: 
[Verband Deutscher Verkehrsunternehmen (VDV) - Ist-Daten-Schnittstellen](http://www.vdv.de/module/layout_upload/schema_vdv453_v2_3e.zip)

The command line I tried (amongst others) was:

```
xjc -readOnly -d generated -npa -target 2.1 -verbose VDV453_incl_454_V2.3e.xsd
```

Any help or hint is greatly appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution here was to use the `-nv` switch to disable strict validation.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is caused by XJC's failure to load the other schema document successfully.  You have several options.

- The xjc documentation suggests that it accepts multiple command-line arguments, so try specifying all the schema documents you want it to read as command-line arguments.
- You can also try to figure out what base URI it's using for resolving relative references, or (more directly) ...
- You can (try to) figure out how to tell XJC what base URI to use.
- Since XJC also supports XML catalogs, you may be able to use a catalog to tell it where to find the files your top-level schema document is referring to.

Comment: Would it then make a difference if I specified a directory where all the schemas and dependent schemas are? I have already tried that to no success.